# How can I annotate a maximum limit to a function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, type-hinting

For example

```
def function(param):
# do something
# return value
```

By using [Type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), I can make the user aware of the type of the parameter `param` and the return value `value` like this:

```
def function(param : int)-> str:
# do something
# return value
```

Is there a way to make the user aware of the maximum value which can be passed to the function `function`?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say the user, you mean the developer? if so you could just make a early exception if the parameter(s) exceed what is expected.

Comment: Please clearly define what you want. "a way to make the user aware" can be anything from annotations, to runtime checks, to docstrings, to random blog post. Are you specifically looking for a type hint that is constrained, or is that just an example you tried and rejected?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a type hint.

Comment: Can you add an example supporting your need??

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Use a [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) if very few values are valid, or a [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NewType) if programmatic validation is desired.

---

A `Literal` allows to statically define which values are allowed.

```py
from typing import literal

def digit_name(digit: Literal[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) -> str: ...


digit_name(6)   # valid
digit_name(12)  # invalid
```

Note that while `Literal` technically only means *these values*, various type checkers do allow only actual *literals for these values*.

---

A `NewType` is a low-overhead specialisation of a type. Use it with a gatekeeper that checks the type at runtime to reject invalid values.

```py
from typing import NewType

# Digit is a plain `int` at runtime, but a subclass for type checking
Digit = NewType('Digit', int)


def assert_digit(candidate: int) -> Digit:
    assert 0 <= candidate <= 9  # assert can be optimised away with `-O` if the program is known to be correct
    return Digit(candidate)

def digit_name(digit: Digit) -> str: ...


a_digit = assert_digit(3)
print(a_digit, 'is', digit_name(a_digit))        # valid
print(a_digit, 'is still', digit_name(a_digit))  # valid
print(3, 'is also still', digit_name(3))         # invalid
```

This pattern allows to establish a boundary between "any value" and "verified value". While the gatekeeper must be explicitly invoked and performs a runtime check, static type checking ensures that the gatekeeper *must* be invoked but *once* is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The type of a parameter can be checked (to a point) by a compiler or pre-compiler) at design time. For example, if you call the function using some variable or expression for the parameter, the compiler can check if the expression should have the same type as is expected for the parameter.

However, the *value* of the parameter can only be decided at runtime - i.e. when the program is running. So, no, you cannot get type hints that would limit the parameter in that way. You can have a docstring provide that information though, so the user would be able to find out if they checked, but the compiler or IDE won't help.

There's two other ways out:

- define a new type that can only have the range of values you're willing to allow
- have the function raise an exception (at runtime) when it gets passed the wrong value

A new type:

```
class Int0To9(int):
    def __init__(self, value):
        assert value in range(10)
        super().__init__()


def my_func(x: Int0To9):
    print(x)


# this one will work, but shows a type hint in a good IDE
my_func(1)
# this one will also work, but shows a type hint in a good IDE - this may be a problem, the value is out of range
my_func(10)
# this one works, as expected, no hints
my_func(Int0To9(2))
# this one raises an AssertionError, before the function is even called, as the Int0To9 cannot be instantiated
try:
    my_func(Int0To9(11))
except AssertionError:
    print('error, as expected (11)')


def my_safe_func(x: int):
    assert x in range(10)
    print(x)


# no problem
my_safe_func(3)
# This now raises an assertion error as well
try:
    my_safe_func(12)
except AssertionError:
    print('error, as expected (12)')
# no problem here still
my_safe_func(Int0To9(4))


def my_very_safe_func(x: Int0To9):
    assert x in range(10)
    print(x)


# this one gives a type hint and fails correctly
try:
    my_very_safe_func(13)
except AssertionError:
    print('error, as expected (13)')
# this one gives a type hint but succeeds if you run it, as expected
my_very_safe_func(5)
# only this one runs correctly without hints
my_very_safe_func(Int0To9(6))
# this one also fails, as before
try:
    my_very_safe_func(Int0To9(14))
except AssertionError:
    print('error, as expected (14)')
```

Result:

```
1
10
2
error, as expected (11)
3
error, as expected (12)
4
error, as expected (13)
5
6
error, as expected (14)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is using docstring, so when the user types help(function) he can see whatever you wrote in docstring.

**Example**

```
def function(param : int)-> str:
    """
    This function does this and returns this
    :param param: integer with a maximum of 100
    :return: anything
    """
    # do something
    # return value
```

so then when the user type

`help(function)`

he will see a help message like this:

```
Help on function function in module __main__:

function(param: int) -> str
    This function does this and returns this
    :param param: integer with a maximum of 100
    :return: anything
(END)
```

**Note**

If the user is using the function in Pycharm (I don't know if it works the same in other editors), he can see the help menu only by hover over the name of the function.